# Xcode seems to be confused about the type of parameter required by a function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a `UIViewController` class in which I have this function:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
...
    func DegreesToRadians(degrees: Double) -> Double
    {
        return degrees * .pi / 180.0
    }
...
}
```

It works just fine within the scope of that class.

However, I'm trying to call this function from within another class

```
class VoltageVectorsViewController: UIViewController {
...
    func DrawVoltageVector(context: UIGraphicsImageRendererContext, color: CGColor, angleDeg: Double )
    {
...
        /* this is telling me: 
            Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'ViewController'
        */
        let voltageAngleRadians = ViewController.DegreesToRadians(angleDeg)
...
    }

...
}
```

See below where Xcode seems to be getting confused as to the parameter types.. what is going on? How do I resolve this?

[image: code completion]

[image]

Why is it wanting `self: ViewController` instead of `Double` as per the func definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode is indeed confused because you call an **instance** method on the **class**.

A solution is to make the function a class method.

And please name functions/methods with starting lowercase letter

```
static func degreesToRadians(degrees: Double) -> Double
{
    return degrees * .pi / 180.0
}
```

Another minor confusion is that the function is actually not related to the view controller with regards to contents.

For example you could create an extra struct for trigonometric functions

```
struct Trigonometry {
    static func degreesToRadians(degrees: Double) -> Double
    {
        return degrees * .pi / 180.0
    }
}
```

and call it

```
let voltageAngleRadians = Trigonometry.degreesToRadians(angleDeg)
```

Comment: thanks!  so simple.  I am confused about the swift documentation re: func definitions and static vs. global... but at least, I can continue my project, and decipher later.

Comment: @DoYouLikeHam don`t ignore accept the answer please

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion vadian... first app written in 10+ years, so mostly prototyping to learn... cleanup/refactoring as I go... e.g., I know I should put this in a separate class.. but clearly, not knowing how to call a function from another class precluded that.